# Html meta keywords should contain commas?

Tags: html, meta-tags

is it important to use commas in the meta keywords?

What if I don't have the commas?

Comment: Get a different keyboard? Surely you can find one that has commas.  :-)

Answer (score 10):

According to the [W3 standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/appendix/notes.html#recs):

> Provide keywords and descriptions
>
> Some indexing engines look for META elements that define a comma-separated list of keywords/phrases, or that give a short description. Search engines may present these keywords as the result of a search. The value of the name attribute sought by a search engine is **not defined by this specification**.

In other words, it's not defined by the HTML standard what a `meta` with `name="keywords"` should look like.  It all depends on what your targetting.  Some search engines use commas in a keywords `meta` tag to separate keywords.  Some ignore such `meta` tags completely.

Comment: In practice, all search engines that care about the keywords list use a comma-separated format as described by bobince. The document you quoted says the whole practice of putting keywords in a meta tag is not defined by the standard. But even it notes that keyword lists are usually comma-separated.

Answer (score 4):

> What if I don't have the commas?

Then your keyword is the whole phrase together. So with keywords “lemon cake”, it won't match when you're searching merely for “lemon” or “cake”.

In reality meta-keywords is at best no more effective than simply having the words included in your page, and at worst totally ignored. So there's very little point using it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually most searchengines ignore the keyword meta element. So actually you could just erase it and save som bytes... :P

Answer (score 0):

I agree that you can probably just ignore the tag as for example Google does not use them. Yahoo however does seem to use it (at least at the end of 2007), so if you want some more information, I found [this article](http://searchengineland.com/meta-keywords-tag-101-how-to-legally-hide-words-on-your-pages-for-search-engines-12099) an interesting read.

Comment: To summarise, the article's conclusion is that there are no use cases for meta keywords for the two search engines that support them that are not better served by reworking page content, which works for all search engines.  Note that the article is linked to from [Google Webmaster Central](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html).

Answer (score -3):

No, just space ... at least this works for me :)

Comment: what works for you? what is the effect of adding meta keywords?

Comment: Well, I don't know if it's just me, but things I include in keywords meta tag usually help a little. But this applies to Seznam.cz - largest search engine in my country. I don't know what Google does, but from other answers I guess it ignores it. Use what's best at your locality :)