# SEO for common misspellings

Tags: html, seo, metadata

*Here's the general question that I'm asking:*
**How do you optimise your website so that searches using common misspellings of your name find their way to you?**

*And my specific situation:*
At my company, we sell online education courses. These are given a code of two letters followed by two numbers, eg: BE01, BE02, IH01.

These courses have been around for some time now *(9 years, which is like 63 internet years or something)*, and since our target market is fairly niche, most of our marketing comes from word-of-mouth from the small community.

I was looking at our statistics to see the search keywords used to get to our site, and the highest ranked one which wasn't just our company name was "BE10", which is one of our *least* popular courses. This made me think that people are typing in how they hear other people refer to the courses verbally, that is: "bee-ee-oh-one" - `BEO1` (not `BE01`).

Looking at some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081/html-meta-keyword-description-element-useful-or-not) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623554/html-meta-keywords-should-contain-commas), and they say that the `keywords` meta tag is virtually useless, and that that information should go into the content of the page. I obviously don't want to perpetuate the misconception that our courses are called `BEO1` by putting that into the content, so what should I do?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend making separate informational pages on the misspellings (http://example.com/beo1.html or what-have-you) that include a brief explanation about the confusion and refer to the correct course page.  Get these indexed by including them in your sitemap (presumably you have one already), and if you like, improve their likelihood of indexing and their ranking by linking them in an inconspicuous "common misspellings" section in the real course pages.

Comment: By 'sitemap' I mean XML sitemap for search engines, btw, not the kind for humans.